# Hierarchial taxonomy terms in Wordpress search page URL

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting, taxonomy-terms

I want to create a Wordpress site with friendly URLs in the search page. I have a custom post type named `cosmetic` and I have custom taxonomies for that post type named `cosmetic_type` and `cosmetic_region`. I have a taxonomy term associated with `cosmetic_type` called `manicure`, and I have a taxonomy term associated with `cosmetic_region` called "north", with a child term called "city1".

When I reach /search/all, I want to see all the custom posts from `cosmetic` in the search page.

When I reach /search/manicure/north/city1, I want to see all the posts associated with these terms.

When I reach /search/all/north, I want to see all posts associated with `north`.

The URL is supposed to be hierarchial, but I want the user to be able to choose from 2 different taxonomies when searching, if he so chooses, which is why I created 2 different taxonomies, instead of 1 with multiple hierarchies.

How would I go about doing that? I know I'm supposed to be using rewrite rules, but I've never worked with rewrite rules before and my attempts to implement snippets and suiting them to my needs have seemed futile so far.

Comment: Yes, You can do that by adding some re-write rules & modify the search query.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to functions.php

```
    function custom_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^search/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)?', 'index.php?post_type=cosmetic&cosmetic_type=$matches[1]&cosmetic_region=$matches[2]&city=$matches[3]', 'top');
    add_rewrite_rule('^search/([^/]+)/([^/]+)?', 'index.php?post_type=cosmetic&cosmetic_region=$matches[1]&city=$matches[2]', 'top');
    add_rewrite_rule('^search/all/?', 'index.php?post_type=cosmetic', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rules');
```

and then you have to modify the main query on the search page based on the URL parameters. Thanks!